# In file editing, how to replace all the string words with incremental integers?

Tags: string, bash, file, edit

I have a file containing a lot of string words, severed by pipes. I would like to have a script (written in bash or in any other programming language) that is able to replace every word with an incremental unique integer (something like an ID).

From an input like this:

```
aaa|ccccc|ffffff|iii|j
aaa|ddd|ffffff|iii|j
bb|eeee|hhhhhh|iii|k
```

I'd like to have something like this

```
1|3|6|8|9
1|4|6|8|9
2|5|7|8|10
```

That is: `aaa` has been replaced by `1`, `bb` has been replaced by `2`, and so on.

How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk to the rescue...
this will do the numbering row-wise, I'm not sure it's important enough to make it columnar.

```
awk -F "|" -vOFS="|" '{
     line=sep="";
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(!a[$i])a[$i]=++c;
        line=line sep a[$i];
        sep=OFS
     }
     print line
}' words

1|2|3|4|5
1|6|3|4|5
7|8|9|4|10
```

to get the word associations into another file, you can replace

```
if(!a[$i])a[$i]=++c;
```

with

```
if(!a[$i]){
     a[$i]=++c; 
     print $i"="a[$i] > "assoc"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly :-) Side question: do you know how to save the list of word-number associations (aaa=1, bb=2, ccccc=3, etc) in another file as well ?

Comment: Thanks but the word association file generation does not work to me... inputFile="inputfile.txt"
outputFile="outputfile.txt"
awk -F "|" -vOFS="|" '{
     line=sep="";
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
       if(!a[$i]){
   a[$i]=++c; 
   print $i"="a[$i] > $outputFile
      }
        line=line sep a[$i];
        sep=OFS
     }
     print line
}' $inputFile // What's wrong?

Comment: that's not how argument passing in `awk` works.  Remove the `$` from outputFile.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an associative array

```
declare -A array
```

use the word as keys and an incremental number as value

```
array[aaa]=$n
```

then replace the original words by the values